# Set up differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> As people get older, they perceive time differently. The older one is, the faster time goes by. To quantify this issue, we create a model: The entire perceived period of time shall be $w(t)$ . A perceived period of time $dt$ causes an increase $dw$ of the entire perceived time $w(t)$, where the increase $dw$ is proportional to the period of time $dt$ with the factor $k$ and direct inversely proportional to the entire perceived time $w(t)$.

My task is to set up and solve a differential equation with this information. What I can get from the text is 
$$w(t+dt) = w(t)+dw $$
$$dw = k \cdot dt$$
$$dw=\frac{1}{w(t)}$$ .

I guess if I had set up the equation, I could solve it myself. 
But how do I do that?

**Note**: Yes it is homework, but I just want a hint how to set up the equation.

Comment: Do you know if $w$ is invertible? and do you know for sure that the differential $dt$ is inside the argument of $w$?

Comment: No, I have no information about $w$ being invertible (at least I would say so). And as I wrote, the three equations is what I can extract from the text (I am not native, please feel free to ask if you don't understand something due to grammar or translation mistakes)

Comment: Why don't you say that $dw=kw(t)dt$? Then $w(t)=e^{kt}$.

Comment: Or rather $w(t)=e^{kt}-1$ because $w(0)=0$ on earth.

Comment: Because it says "the increase $dw$ is proportional to $dt$ with the factor $k$" and not "the increase $dw$ is proportional to $w(t) dt$ " ?

Comment: Then $dw$ does not depend on $t$. That is, the perceived time is linear. $w(t)=kt$. Now $dw=kdt$.

Comment: Well, in slightly different words: "the increase dw is proportional to the time spawn dt with the proportional factor k". But $w(t)$ being linear wouldn't make sense considering the actual problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me risk then the following Answer:

The right interpretation of the case is that $$dw=\frac{kdt}{w(t)}.$$
And a solution for $k=1$ is $$w(t)=\sqrt{2t}$$ if $t \ge0$ and undefined otherwise.
(Also, by common sense: $w(0)=0$.)

Comment: Oh yes, this would make sense in the original task. As you saw, I always thought it should be 2 equations - thanks

Comment: I think $k$ should be in the square root as well, since what I did now is $dw = \frac{k \cdot dt}{w} $ , thus $w dw = kdt$ and by integration I get $w=\sqrt{2kt}$

Comment: I am still having a problem with this interpretation and solution. The resulting function describes creatures that perceive time as going slower and not faster...

Comment: No, it is correct :)
Consider the following: When you are 80 years old, after how many years have you lived half of your *perceived* time ?
So, $\frac12 w(80) = w(t_{1/2})$ => $t_{1/2} = 20$ which does make sense

Comment: I am only 64! So I don't know.

Comment: See, if I get to be 80 years old, I haven't reached half of my perceived time yet ;)